# How to retain environment for different jobs in azure pipeline

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

Stage can keep all the running environments for its jobs, but I have several different jobs that logically cannot grouped into the same stage. all of these jobs has the same running environment, I don't want to repeat the following code to each jobs, how can I abstract all this steps into some sort of functions and call by each job. Or how can I create a shared environment for those jobs. Or how can I retain the environment instead of groups them all into the same stage?

```
 steps:
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
        displayName: Add Conda to PATH

      - bash: conda env update -f environment.yml --name $(Agent.Id)
        displayName: Create Conda Environment

      - bash: export PYTHONPATH="src/"
        displayName: Add /src to PYTHONAPTH

      - bash: source activate $(Agent.Id)
        displayName: Active Test Environment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put above steps into a template yaml file. And use [step templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#step-templates) to reference it in your main pipeline Yaml file.

For example, create a template yaml file `setEnv.yml` with above codes.

```
#File: setEnv.yml

steps:
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
    displayName: Add Conda to PATH

  - bash: conda env update -f environment.yml --name $(Agent.Id)
    displayName: Create Conda Environment
    ...
```

Use `template` to reference the above template file.

```
 # File: azure-pipelines.yml
  stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - job: macOS
      pool:
        vmImage: 'macOS-10.14'
      steps:
      - template: setEnv.yml # Template reference
      - othertasks: 
 - stage: B
   jobs:
   - job: Linux
     pool:
       vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
     steps:
     - template: setEnv.yml # Template reference
     - othertasks:
```

Check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#template-references) for more information.

Comment: can I some how put it into a code block in the Azure-pipelines.yml file and refer it when needed?

Comment: I am afraid this cannot be done currently. YAML pipeline doesnot support referring to a code block defined inside its Azure-pipelines.yml file.